# Background data fetching in Android

Tags: android, android-activity

I've this android application which is like yellow pages, but niche specific data. I'm stuck with pushing the new data (like new phone numbers, updated emails, contact information etc.) to the application.

The app also has a ranking feature where I can update a users rank for a product category from the web based admin panel. Currently, the new data is being stored in the local db when app is started with an active internet connection. If there's no internet then the previously fetched data is used from the local db of the app.

Now, I'm confused about how to push the new data in the background to the device for offline usage. What is the best way to update the rank and other information in the background without messing with the User Experience.

Answer (score 0):

The best thing for background updates might be the `IntentService`. It is easy to implement and does the job.

If you really want to force-push the data from the server, you can use Google Cloud Messaging.

Comment: Can you please provide me some more information about the same. I've read about google cloud messaging, but I don't have much know about it.

Answer (score 0):

Try Async task Library, Looks like this

```
private class LongOperation extends AsyncTask<Void, String, String> {

      @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {}

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            ....
           //do some task
           ............
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            //Display reasult
        }

}
```

This is perfect for doing background task as the UI thread is in foreground.

Read more about it from http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: This is actually very poor way of doing background tasks as AsyncTask is very tied to Activity Context, has poor API and will be destroyed each time phone is rotated.

Comment: What other ways can you suggest Gaskion :-)